# ocg + tikz + How to show one value and hide the other?

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, ocg

I have an array of "3D buttons" (the array will have more that 100 buttons). Clicking on a button I want to show the "OCG of the button" and hide the other OCG's. How can I do it?

Below is an example of what I want but **I do not know how to hide the other values.**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{ocgx} 
\tikzstyle{button}=[minimum width=15mm, rounded corners,  draw=white!50!black!100,  bottom color=white]

\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[button, show ocg=0] (0) {$\mathbf{0}$};
\foreach \x  [evaluate={\xi=int(\x-1);}] [evaluate={\i=int(\x);}] in {1,2,...,7}  {\node[button, show ocg=\i] [right of=\xi, xshift=20pt]  (\x) {$\mathbf{\x}$};}
\foreach \x  [evaluate={\xi=int(\x-8);}] [evaluate={\i=int(\x);}] in {8,9,...,11} {\node[button, show ocg=\i] [below of=\xi]  (\x) {$\mathbf{\x}$};} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{ocg}{OCG 0}{0}{1}\node {$0,0,0,0$};\end{ocg}  
\foreach \x  in {1,2,...,11} {\begin{ocg}{OCG \x}{\x}{0}\node {$\x,\x,\x,\x$};\end{ocg}}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacement package **`ocgx2`** implements *Radio Button Groups*:

From `texdoc ocgx2`:

> Layers can be added to one or several Radio Button Groups using the
>   new option **`radiobtngrp`**. From all layers within a Radio Button Group
>   only one can be enabled at a time. Enabling a layer, e. g. in the
>   Layers tab of the PDF viewer, automatically hides the previously
>   visible layer.

Just add all OCGs in the array to the *same* Radio Button Group, e. g.:

```
\begin{ocg}[radiobtngrp=myRadioButtons]{OCG 0}{0}{1}...\end{ocg}
```

---

**Complete example (modified from OP):**

(If `ocgx` was used before, `*.aux` must be deleted first.)

Open on [ShareLaTeX](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/58af3b450cbb2f2f37d9e6af)

---

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{ocgx} 
\usepackage[tikz]{ocgx2}
\tikzstyle{button}=[minimum width=15mm, rounded corners,  draw=white!50!black!100,  bottom color=white]

\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[button, show ocg=0] (0) {$\mathbf{0}$};
\foreach \x  [evaluate={\xi=int(\x-1);}] [evaluate={\i=int(\x);}] in {1,2,...,7}  {\node[button, show ocg=\i] [right of=\xi, xshift=20pt]  (\x) {$\mathbf{\x}$};}
\foreach \x  [evaluate={\xi=int(\x-8);}] [evaluate={\i=int(\x);}] in {8,9,...,11} {\node[button, show ocg=\i] [below of=\xi]  (\x) {$\mathbf{\x}$};}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{ocg}[radiobtngrp=myRadioButtons]{OCG 0}{0}{1}\node {$0,0,0,0$};\end{ocg}
\foreach \x  in {1,2,...,11} {\begin{ocg}[radiobtngrp=myRadioButtons]{OCG \x}{\x}{0}\node {$\x,\x,\x,\x$};\end{ocg}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you AlexG. Unfortunately my distribution of TeX is 2014 and it does not contain the ocgx2.sty. After downloading the package and the additional file pdfbase.sty there was (running tex) enormous number of errors. I'm afraid that I will have to reinstall my TeX distribution, if there is no other solution :-(.

Comment: A lot has evolved during the recent years ; an upgrade to TeXLive-2016 is worth the effort ;-).

Comment: @alphabeta For testing, you may have an online service typset the document, such as ShareLaTeX or Overleaf.

Comment: @alphabeta I added a link to the example on ShareLaTeX.

Comment: Answer is great, the link to ShareLaTeX works. But what exactly do you mean by "accept the answer"? Sorry but this is my first using of tex.stackexchange.com.

Comment: You can click the checkmark on the left side of the answer.